# Do not understand assertRaises with generators + unittest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, generator, raise

I do not understand what's wrong. Here is 2 simple range generators. Both raise ValueError on input bigger than MAX. First one is generator comprehension and second one uses yield.

```
MSG = 'Wrong number'
MAX = 20

def test_compr(n, m=MAX):
    if n > m:
        raise ValueError('{} {} in {}'.format(MSG, n, test_compr.__name__))
    return (i for i in range(n))

def test_yield(n, m=MAX):
    if n > m:
        raise ValueError('{} {} in {}'.format(MSG, n, test_yield.__name__))
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

def main():
    n = 30

    try:
        print(list(test_compr(n)))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        print(list(test_yield(n)))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

```
python3 --version  && python t.py
Python 3.7.5
Wrong number 30 in test_compr
Wrong number 30 in test_yield
```

This works as intended. 
Now some unittest tests to make sure ValueError is actually raised.

```
import unittest
from t import test_compr, test_yield

N_BIG = 30
N_OK = 19


# test generator comprehension
class TestCompr(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ok(self):
        tst = N_OK
        g = test_compr(tst)
        for num in range(tst):
            self.assertEqual(num, next(g))

    def test_exception(self):
        TST = N_BIG
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as c:
            test_compr(N_BIG)

# test yield
class TestYield(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ok(self):
        tst = N_OK
        g = test_yield(tst)
        for num in range(tst):
            self.assertEqual(num, next(g))

    def test_exception(self):
        tst=N_BIG
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as c:
            test_yield(tst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
> python3 tests.py
Python 3.7.5
..F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_exception (__main__.TestYield)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 31, in test_exception
    test_yield(tst)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Test with generator comprehension raises error but generator with yield does not. As soon as I remove yield I see unittest producing correct result on assertRaises

Tried to install latest python.  Same problem.

```
python3.8 --version && python3.8 tests.py
Python 3.8.0
..F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_exception (__main__.TestYield)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 31, in test_exception
    test_yield(tst)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Not sure what is wrong and how to fix this. I started with slightly more complicated code on python3.5 with pretty much same results. Made boilerplate above to reproduce problem on straightforward code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this seemingly inconsistent behaviour is the following:

- `test_yield` is a generator function
- `test_compr` is a function that returns a generator

This means, that when you call `test_compr` the function body will immediately be executed, and as its result returns a generator (or throws).

In contrast, when you call `test_yield`, you receive a generator object.  The execution of a generator does not start upon creation, but instead once the `next` function is called for the first time.  Therefore, your test function should look like follows:

```
def test_exception(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as c:
        g = test_yield(N_BIG)
        next(g)
```